# How can I group by in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in which I have details of manager and its lead sources(Google, website, Mobile app). I need to find count per manager how many leads he got from different sources in pandas.

I tried using group-by but I am not able to find the count of lead source per Manager

Comment: give some code that you have already tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df.groupby(by="ManagerName").sum()
```